# *ngIf function gets called infinitely

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

In my component I am iterating over a list which I have received from the ngRx store state:

```
<div class="employees-component">
  <div *ngFor="let employee of users">
    <div *ngIf="canShowEmployee(employee)">
      <span>{{ employee.firstName }} {{ employee.lastName }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My users list arrives asynchronously from the ngRx state on ngInit :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.pipe(select( state => state.slotAssignment.users))
      .subscribe((users: IUser[]) => {
        this.users = users;
      });
  }
```

I would expect the "canShowEmployee" function to run only when the state.users was updated. Instead it runs infinitely and hangs the page.

(the users list is updated on the store as a result from an api get call which runs only once on page load).

Can anyone advice?

Comment: Don't use functions in bindings. your function will be called on every change detection cycle. and angular runs x2 cycles in dev mode.

Comment: can you add canShowEmployee(employee) code.

Comment: For the sake of debugging I set the canShowEmployeeCode to be : console.log('running function canshowemployee');
    return true;